# 'Shove' feats and 'shoving' weapons

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, combat-maneuver

In 2E of Pathfinder - there is a number of fighter feats that allow to automatically shove opponent in certain conditions, icluding [Agressive Block](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=363) and [Brutish Shove](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=365).
But, at the same time Shove as action requires either free hand or weapon with Shove trait.

Question - does that requirement applies to feats that allow to automatically shove opponents or is it ignored by them?

Answer (score 8):

### Generally, you don't need to meet the requirements for such Feats

For the example Feats, and even more for some others, such as [Clear a Path](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=918), they almost make it impossible to meet the Shove action's requirement. Based on this, the Activities/Actions are exceptions to the rules for Shove. See [Ambiguous Rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312):

> Sometimes a rule could be interpreted multiple ways. If one version is too good to be true, it probably is. **If a rule seems to have wording with problematic repercussions or doesn’t work as intended**, work with your group to find a good solution, rather than just playing with the rule as printed.

If the Feat allows you to use Shove while your hands are otherwise full, you should assume the language is written in a way to allow you to do so.

---

Additionally, I think most of the abilities are written in a way that does allow the Shove to occur without a free hand or Shove-traited weapon.

- Aggressive Block - "**You use your shield to push the triggering creature**, either **automatically** Shoving it 5 feet or causing it to become flat-footed until the start of your next turn." (No Shove *Action* used)
- Brutish Shove - "...you can **automatically** Shove it, with the **same benefits** as the Shove action..." (No Shove *Action* used)
- Clear a Path - "For this Shove, you don't need a free hand..."
- Clear the Way - No specific allowance "You put your body behind your massive weapon and swing, shoving enemies to clear a wide path. You attempt to Shove up to five creatures adjacent to you"
- Drive Back - "Your shield has the shove trait for this Shove attempt."
- Knockback - "You push the foe back 5 feet, with **the effects of** a successful Shove."
- Running Tackle - No specific allowance (but might be an oversight because the Activity also allows an unarmed attack)
- Shoving Sweep - "..., ignoring the requirement that you have a hand free."

The two feats you mention, Aggressive Block and Brutish Shove, don't actually require the character to *perform* the Shove action; you are just getting the *effects* of it (arguably, Aggressive Block isn't even the same as using the Shove action at all for other effects that might trigger off of a Shove, but it's capitalized so I assume using the game term was intentional).

Clear the Way seems to be the only such Feat (that I could find searching Actions and Feats with the word "Shove" in them) that *might* require a Shove weapon (or otherwise having a 'free hand')... and that seems very unlikely given its context in the Mauler archetype.

Comment: Clear a Path, mentioned above, specifically states in the feat itself that 'you don't need a free hand', which feats mentioned as examples lack. So, based on it, other feats should either have such addition or require free hand or weapon with 'shove' trait.

Comment: Fair, and some others like Brutish Shove are ambiguous regarding if you're doing the Shove action or just using the effects it causes. I could see this causing problems with other sub-Actions like using an ability that lets you Step or Leap then do something while Immobilized... but I think that's a different circumstance (being allowed to avoid requirements is much more likely than being able to ignore restrictions)

Comment: But I do believe my answer to be accurate, bad example nonwithstanding. Leaving out "even if you don't meet the free hand requirement" seems like an oversight in abilities that require a shield or two-handed weapon.

Comment: while your answer is good, it is not based on any rules, rules clarifications and so on. So, while it may be closest to RAI, it doesn't go well with RAW. Still, thank you for sharing your view and opinion.

Comment: @Sarge I'm not ignoring your comment, I do plan to improve my answer (it is founded on a rule), I just haven't had time to find the specific text I'm thinking of. I also want to comb back through the abilities to see if there is any more specific text to further support this (such as Brutish Shove not requiring you to *make* a Shove attempt)

Comment: if you'd find a rule to rely on - I'd be happy to see it. This far my attempts only raised more questions. Like - whether there are any limits on where one can shove target with Agressive block and if it's possible to choose to shove an enemy, who doesn't want to be flat-footed into the one, who is shoving for desired effect.